# Edge case: Can you configure Net.Core 3.1 to run in the same folder as Asp.Classic?

Tags: c#, web-config, iis-8, httphandler, isapi

I am looking at migrating a huge Asp.Classic (3K files) to Net.Core 3.1 in steps (i.e. folder by folder migration). We have figured out issues with sharing sessions and prefer not to go parallel sites (but may end going there if there is not a simple solution).

One line (in <-- --> below) in a merged Web.Config determines if Asp.Classic loads or Net.Core loads.

- Commented out: Asp.Classic
- Uncomment: Net.Core

```html
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <!--<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />-->
      </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
```

I realize that ISAPI filter written in C++ is a possibility (in one way easy: if there is an .asp in the request go to Asp.Classic, otherwise pass to Net.Core). Any alternatives before walking that path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to host classic asp and asp.net core at same IIS web site, you should modify your hanlder mapping to make the classic asp handler above the asp.net core module.

Details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Open the IIS management console and select handler mapping:

[image]

2.Click the ordered list:

[image]

3.Move the classic asp up than the aspnet core

[image]

Comment: Looked like a brilliant solution and it worked as advertised. I now have to sort out the ordering of the other two dozen filters.

I have been away in the Starbuck's world of high volume, high performance REST calls only and forgot the obvious..

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant solution!!! You forget too much when you end up being siloed in doing just high performance/high volume REST API's at Starbucks for many years.

For clarification, Brando's solution works with both .Asp and .cshtml file loading on the test site.

This caused the Web.Config to become much bigger... and I need to get some issues sorted out, specifically:

- Where will static files come from (classic folder structure or netcore folder structure)

```html
    <handlers>
                <clear />
                <add name="ASPClassic" path="*.asp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
                <add name="rules-Integrated" path="*.rules" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
                <add name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.rem" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-soap-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.soap" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="rules-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.rules" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```